# how to join multiple 3 xmls in one file?

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

how to join multiple 3 xmls in one file?

In XML FILE : 01.xml

```
 <xmlResponse>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>FirstName_1</FirstName>
            <LastName>LastName_1</LastName>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
            <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
        </Person>
    </xmlResponse>
```

In XML FILE : 02.xml

```
<xmlResponse>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_3</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_3</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_4</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_4</LastName>
    </Person>
</xmlResponse>
```

In XML FILE : 03.xml

```
<xmlResponse>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_5</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_5</LastName>
    </Person>
</xmlResponse>
```

I need output like below (01.xml + 02.xml + 03.XML)

```
<xmlResponse>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_1</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_1</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_3</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_3</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_4</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_4</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>FirstName_5</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_5</LastName>
    </Person>
</xmlResponse>
```

hoping your response,
tks...

Comment: Could you give a hint on the direction you would like to take to do this? E.g. do you want to use some XML library, or only strip the first and last lines in each of the files and concatenate the contents?

Comment: We also need to know if XMLs are distinct or has some intersection

Answer (score 0):

Try this XSLT 2.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:param name="doc2" /> <!-- File 02.xml -->
<xsl:param name="doc3" /> <!-- File 03.xml -->
<xsl:variable name="doc2-doc" select="document($doc2)" />
<xsl:variable name="doc3-doc" select="document($doc3)" />

<xsl:template  match="/">
 <xmlResponse>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2-doc/*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc3-doc/*" />
 </xmlResponse>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity transform follows. -->
<xsl:template match="element()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="attribute()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the transformation, the input document will be your first document (File 01.xml), and the other two will be passed in as transform parameters.

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, some modification will be required, but it should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT buts it an overkill for this task under ASP Classic (or actually anything else).

(Assuming you haven't mis-tagged your question)

```
Function GetDom(pathToFile)
    Set GetDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    GetDom.async = False
    GetDom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    GetDom.load pathToFile
End Function

Sub CopyElements(xmlPrimeRoot, xmlDonor)
    Dim elem
    For Each elem In xmlDonor.documentElement.selectNodes("*")
        xmlPrimeRoot.appendChild elem 
    Next  
End Sub

Dim xmlPrime: Set xmlPrime = GetDom(pathToFile1)

CopyElements xmlPrime.documentElement, GetDom(pathToFile2)
CopyElements xmlPrime.documentElement, GetDom(pathToFile3)

xmlPrime.save pathToDestinationFile
```

If the target output is the ASP response then the last line can be

```
xmlPrime.save Response
```